# I am trying to identify the mint variety that I have

Tags: identification, mint

I have a mint from my grandmother's garden that has wide leaves with a whitish fuzz on them. I only know it as Lebanese mint because she brought it over from the old country. Can you tell me what variety I have?

Comment: Can you add a photograph please?